# Composition using child classes rather than external data

Tags: reactjs

I'm thinking about building a static blog using ReactJS on my website to get more familiar with the framework and best practices. I've been going through the docs and the questions asked here, but cannot find information on what I want to do specifically (which might indicate it is a bad idea or anti-pattern, but I'll ask anyway).

I'd like to have a single Blog class that composes individual posts (which are just React classes) and displays them. Before displaying, I'd like to sort the posts and possibly do other things in the future. The important difference between this and the comment tutorial on the docs is the "data" for the blog isn't coming from some external json file or database; it's simply other React classes on the page.

I want to compose the individual blog classes in separate files and put them on some global array for consumption by the main Blog class. Something like:

```
var Blog = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
     return {posts:window.__posts}
   },
   render: function() {
     var posts = {};

     this.state.posts.forEach(function(post) {
       var postCls = post();
       posts[_.uniqueId()] = postCls;
     });

     return (
       <div className="section-content">
         { posts }
       </div>
     );
   }
 });
```

With my individual blog classes being like:

```
    var MyFirstBlogPost = React.createClass({
      displayName: 'MyFirstBlogPost',
      getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
          date: 1406834820,
          tags: [window.__postTags.aPost]
        };
      },
      render: function() {
        return (
          <article className="post">
            My First Blog Post
          </article>
        );
      }
    });

    window.__posts.push(MyFirstBlogPost);
```

My issue is getting props and/or state from the individual blog posts BEFORE rendering them. As I write this out, it feels like a wrong approach and that the data I want to access should not be stored the way I'm doing it - I want the data (object returned from getDefaultProps) available to the individual post as well as the Blog class.

Do I need to store this "meta" information outside of the React structure? Should I maintain it within the Blog class and pass it around? The issue with that approach is the Blog class does not know what specific blog posts it contains - so it couldn't easily map the meta information to the correct post without some kind of layer in the middle.

Any suggestions or tips to get me on the right track?

Comment: You could push an object to the post array instead containing something like `{meta:{}, component: ..}` and then unwind it in your render method. From what I understand it's not a good idea to pull information out of sub components. Is there a reason why your blog needs to render posts like this? Most blogs just use markdown, and compile to html.

Comment: If you're going to be using `renderComponentToStaticMarkup`, you shouldn't be referencing `window`. Rendering to a string is not done in a browser context; there is no "window". You should pass the data to the top-level component when you call `React.renderComponentToStaticMarkup` and pass pieces of the data to other components as `props`.

Comment: Chad - I don't necessarily think it's the best tool for the job, but I wanted to familiarize myself with the framework and wanted to build this blog out for awhile now so I figured I'd knock out two birds with one stone

Comment: ssorallenless - I don't think I mentioned 'renderComponentToStaticMarkup' in the OP, but do you think that's a path I should investigate?

Answer (score 0):

> getting props and/or state **from** the individual blog posts

With react everything goes top-down, from your root component to the lowest span.  So while you can pass data down, you can't just pluck it out.

The approach you're taking here is a bit bizarre.  Without significantly changing it, I believe this is the only way to make it accessible:

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wacitovu/2/edit)

```
var MyFirstBlogPost = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'MyFirstBlogPost',
  statics: {
    date: 1406834820,
    tags: [window.__postTags.aPost]
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <article className="post">
        My First Blog Post {new Date(MyFirstBlogPost.date).toString()}
      </article>
    );
  }
});

window.__posts.push(MyFirstBlogPost);
```

Note, this isn't overridable by the component rendering it... but it shouldn't be because this is data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From both your comment and Chad, it seems like I'm going down the wrong path. What is the recommended approach for handling this, assuming that I want my individual post data to only live in the individual post file? Or is that the part that is making this bizarre?

Comment: The part that's bizarre is you're using React components as posts.  It might make more sense to do something like markdown, and add a syntax extension to embed react components.  Something like `<LikeButton> {"x": "y"}` where it's the component name, and then JSON to be passed as props.  Hard to say without knowing your requirements.

Comment: No requirements actually - just looking to learn more about ReactJS and wanted to make a blog. It sounds like my mindset is wrong for doing this purely with ReactJS. Thanks for the information.